# allow large(r) files to be uploaded

Tags: grails

In my Grails app, I have an action that has an uploaded file parameter. The file is retrieved from the request like so:

```
CommonsMultipartFile cu = params['currencyResult']
```

It works fine if the file size is small, but if I try and upload a 1.3MB file, a "connection was reset" error occurs (execution never reaches the action).

I've tried making the following changes to allow files up to 100MB to be uploaded. In `resources.groovy`, I added the following Spring bean

```
multipartResolver(CommonsMultipartResolver) {
    maxUploadSize = 1000000 * 100 // 100 MB
}
```

In Tomcat's `server.xml`, I added this `maxPostSize` attribute to the `Connector`

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="443"  maxPostSize="100000000"/>
```

But still the upload fails for a 1.3MB file. Is there something else I need to configure in order to allow larger files to be uploaded?

Comment: Which version of Grails & tomcat you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into setting Tomcat's `connectionUploadTimeout` and `disableUploadTimeout`?

**From the [Documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html):**

> **connectionUploadTimeout**
>
> Specifies the timeout, in milliseconds, to use while a data upload is
>   in progress. This only takes effect if disableUploadTimeout is set to
>   false.

**Example:**

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="443"  
           maxPostSize="100000000"
           disableUploadTimeout="false"
           connectionUploadTimeout="300000" />
```

Or in development, you can set this in Grails with the following:

```
eventConfigureTomcat = { tomcat ->
    tomcat.connector.setAttribute('disableUploadTimeout', false);
    tomcat.connector.setAttribute('connectionUploadTimeout', 300000);
}
```

You will want to adjust the timeout value according to your needs.

Comment: I'm experiencing the problem in the production env (only). AFAIK, any configuration in the `_Events.groovy` file you've referred to above is only applied in the dev env.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this by a WS or POST?
if with WS adjust the

```
<scripting>
  <webServices>
    <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="500000000"/>
  </webServices>
 </scripting>
```